# Увеличение и уменьшение кнопки, анимация

Tags: python, анимация, pyqt, pyqt6, qpropertyanimation

Для кнопки `self.pushButtonProfil`e я создал анимацию на увеличение при нажатии, а при втором нажатии она должна вернуться.

Обратный возврат `height` кнопки не работает.

Код написан на PyQt6:

```
class AboutTheProgram(QDialog, Ui_AboutTheProgram):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.nameUsers = None
        self.oldPos = None
        self.ui = None
        self.logo_text = None
        self.abouttheprogram = Ui_AboutTheProgram
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.importmainclass = MainWindows
        self.importregclass = Refistration

        self.nameUsers = os.getlogin()
        if os.path.isfile(f'/Users/{self.nameUsers}\Downloads/soft.txt'):
            os.remove(f'/Users/{self.nameUsers}\Downloads/soft.txt')
            print("success")
        else:
            print("File doesn't exists!")

        #Импорт основных методов передвижение окна windows и убарать windows элементы из виджета.
        self.importmainclass.RemoveWindowsMenu(self)
        self.pushClose.clicked.connect(self.importmainclass.CloseWindow)#кнопка завершение программы
        self.pushCollapse.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)#Сворачивание окна
        self.pushExit.clicked.connect(self.PushBack)#кнопка для выхода с аккаунта
        self.pushDownload.clicked.connect(self.download)


        #Работа с кнопкой профиль
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButtonProfile)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.pushButtonProfile.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)
        self.animation = None
        self.is_expanded = False

    def on_button_clicked(self):
        if not self.animation or self.animation.state() == QAbstractAnimation.State.Stopped:
            if not self.is_expanded:
                self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.pushButtonProfile, b"minimumSize")
                self.animation.setDuration(300)
                self.animation.setStartValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 31))
                self.animation.setEndValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 111))
                self.animation.start()
                self.is_expanded = True
            else:
                self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.pushButtonProfile, b"minimumSize")
                self.animation.setDuration(600)
                self.animation.setStartValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 111))
                self.animation.setEndValue(QSize(self.pushButtonProfile.width(), 31))
                self.animation.start()
                self.is_expanded = False
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: zoomkaXXX, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы почему-то не предоставляете минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Я думаю, что вам надо установите анимацию на геометрию, а не на размер.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn = QPushButton('click', self)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)                           # !!!                   
        self.btn.resize(100, 31)
        self.btn.move(125, 125)
        
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

    def increase(self):
        rect_start = QRect(self.btn.geometry())
        rect_end = QRect(0, 0, 100, 31)
        rect_end.moveCenter(rect_start.center())
        
# ---------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvv <------------ !!!
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.btn, b"geometry", self)
        animation.setStartValue(rect_start)
        animation.setEndValue(rect_end)
        animation.setDuration(1000)
        animation.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    def reduce(self):
        rect_start = QRect(self.btn.geometry())
        rect_end = QRect(0, 0, 100, 111)
        rect_end.moveCenter(rect_start.center())        

# ---------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvv <------------ !!!
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.btn, b"geometry", self)
        animation.setStartValue(rect_start)
        animation.setEndValue(rect_end)
        animation.setDuration(1000)
        animation.start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)
        
    def btn_clicked(self, state):                                   # !!! state
        if state:
            self.reduce()
        else:
            self.increase()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]